# Easy way to migrate a single file between branches in git?

Tags: git

Sometimes I don't realize I'm on the `master` branch in git and don't realize it and I end up committing something to master when I want to commit it to another branch, `dev`.

What I've been doing in this case is just copy the file somewhere else, checkout `dev`, copy the file back, and commit.

I'm sure there is a better way of doing this isn't there?

The `dev` branch is just going to be merged into master anyways. Could I just `git merge master` on the dev branch? There are some branch specific changes that don't seem to get merged when I do `git merge dev` on master. Will those changes get messed up if I merge `master` into `dev`?

Comment: I also had the issue of loosing track of the working branch.  One suggestion, set up git's bash_completion, and $(__git_ps1) to your bash prompt.  (I'm assuming you are using bash on a Unix like platform, msysgit will already do this for you on windows).  It will add the current checkout branch to your prompt.  See [GIT autocompletion and enhanced bash prompt](http://en.newinstance.it/2010/05/23/git-autocompletion-and-enhanced-bash-prompt/) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`git cherry-pick`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-cherry-pick.html) is what you're looking for.

Say, you committed to `master` revision `A` and want to have `A` on `dev` instead:

```
git checkout dev
git cherry-pick A
```

Done. Now, `A` is in `dev`.

We still have to get rid of `A` in `master`. If `A` was the last commit you did, this one will help:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

If there are some more commits since `A`, you could either `git rebase A~` and delete `A` then or – if you pushed to somewhere else – simply `git revert A`.

Comment: but this assumes he already commited to master. is that what he is asking?

Comment: @why-el: that's what he wrote: "**[...] I end up committing something to master [...]**". Sounds to me like he already committed to master, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah but he did not want to, or at least thats what he meant when he said: "when I want to commit it to another branch".

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use

```
git checkout branch_name file_name
```

[This article](http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/) gives a great overview of the advantages of using this pattern over `git cherry-pick` (for certain situations).

edit: Also, I suggest [displaying your current git branch name in your bash prompt](http://hocuspokus.net/2009/07/add-git-and-svn-branch-to-bash-prompt/) to help avoid the kind of confusions you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Merging master into dev is a very common workflow. But if you dont want to merge and still want to do the copy thing, you only need to checkout the dev branch and you can use git to checkout the file:

```
git checkout master -- path/to/file
```